# PHP script isn't interpreted

Tags: php

I'm unable to run the following code in PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head> This is testing of PHP for coding </head>

<body> <h1> <?php echo "Hello Friends"; ?> </h1></body>
</html>
```

This code just displays the line which is in the `<head>` tag, but doesn't show the line in PHP.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add this to top of your file and see what happens, `<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL)?>`

Comment: Do a "view source" and see if you can see the PHP code

Comment: Are you simply referencing the file in your address bar; or are you running through a webserver on localhost?

Comment: Do you have php installed on your computer?  wamp is an easy start for windows, xampp for mac i think

Comment: Does the filename of this script end with `.php` or `.html`?

Comment: PHP files are only executed when run through a server, not when loaded as a local file.

Comment: Is this your entire PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have downloaded `XAMPP` Server and installed `Apache`

1. Open the XAMPP `control panel` and press the button saying `admin`.
2. Then copy the script that you have written (extension must be .php) to the`htdocs` folder.
3. Open Google Chrome and type `localhost`

You will be listed with the file name and if you clicked on it it will run the script and output accordingly!!!